# Would the 2 way Chi Square test be appropriate for this scenario; If not, what test is?

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

The test hypothesis is this:

> Does a student’s gender have a greater influence on their choice in
>   whether they study data science as a core topic; than other
>   demographic/variable factors?

The sample is of a population with 39 students in the class,and the other demographic/variable factors are:

- nationality (Australian or other)
- religion (non-affiliated or religious)
- how they were paying for university[payment] (government help or savings)
- if they had moved house to study[moved] (yes or no)
- if they had chosen data science as an elective or core topic

I was considering performing two chi square tests, one for gender and the core/elective topic, and one for core/elective topics and other demographic/variable factors; as shown below:
[image: possible chi square test contingency table?]

With

- H0: Gender/demographic factors does have a greater influence/relationship with picking a
  core topic
- Ha: Gender/demographic factors does not have a greater influence/relationship with
  picking a core topic

I am to test the hypothesis by viewing the difference between the two table's p-values and to see that if the first table has a smaller p-value than the second's, then we know that gender does have a greater influence.

I am sorry, I don't really understand these statistical tests, would really appreciate it if someone can help interpret analysis that can be performed to answer the test hypothesis.